# What happens when assigning an rvalue to 'const auto&'

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, lvalue, rvalue

What happens in this case?

```
// assume WeakPtr is valid and has not expired
const auto& something = WeakPtr.lock();
something->doStuff();
```

Is this undefined?

Does it change in this scenario?

```
std::shared_ptr<Something> getSomething() { return mSomething.lock(); }
const auto& something = getSomething();
```

And how about this?

```
std::vector<int> getInts() { return std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3 }; }
const auto& ints = getInts();
```

In each of these cases `const auto&` implies that I want to bind a reference to the object, but in each of these cases I am binding it to a temporary rvalue object.  Am I inviting disaster?

Comment: Neat how  questions bunch up like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868517/why-can-you-intialize-a-const-reference-but-not-a-non-const-reference-from-an-rv Some useful commentary on the whys and wherefores.

Comment: It's important to note the difference between "temporary" and "rvalue". The latter is strictly more general. For example, compare `const int& r = 5;` and `const int& q = std::move(5);`. Both are rvalues, one is a disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this undefined?

Each case is well defined.

> What happens in this case?

In each case, the lifetime of the temporary object is extended to match the lifetime of the const reference as is described in the [class.temporary] section of the standard.

> [class.temporary] (standard draft)
>
> 4 There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-
>   expression. The first context is ... [irrelevant to your cases]
>
> 5 The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is
>   bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists
>   for the lifetime of the reference except ... [a few exceptions which do not apply to your cases]

Comment: _"Each case is well defined."_ Well, no, it depends what `WeakPtr.lock()` and `mSomething.lock()` return. The final case is the only assuredly well-defined case.

Comment: Basically, it's well-defined _iff_ a reference to a local is not being returned. Basically.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition in which case is it not well-defined when the function returns a temporary object, an rvalue, as stated in the question? A reference (to a local, or otherwise) is an lvalue.

Comment: No, the question does not guarantee that `WeakPtr.lock()` and `mSomething.lock()` do not return references to locals. The expression's value category is largely irrelevant; the lifetime of the chained reference is.